# Does Pohlig-Hellman algorithm work for non-prime powers?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, pohlig-hellman

I implemented the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm for the general case following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm#The_general_algorithm) but it only seem to work for prime powers (which is what the [limited case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm#Groups_of_prime-power_order) is meant to solve).

My implementation follows wikipedia exactly: https://gist.github.com/nickponline/2ef6f3456ed6c423239a334c98728324

Some examples where it fails to find a solution are:

```
39^x = 49 (mod 74) x = 28
19^x = 423 (mod 478) x = 275
71^x = 65 (mod 86) x = 45
```

I'm unclear why my implementation doesn't work for p where p is not a prime power.

Comment: You are treating the modulus of the multiplicative group ($p$ in your notation) as the order of the multiplicative group. This will not be the case in general. For a prime power $p=q^r$, elements will generally have order $q^{r-1}(q-1)$ and recovering the discrete logarithm mod $q^{r-1}$ may suffice. For general moduli, the best that we can say is that the order of $g$ divides $\lambda(p)$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: Thank you that was indeed the issue.